# jQuery CheckAll Toggle Not Quite Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using:

```
function CheckToggle(which){
    jQuery(which).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).attr('checked', !jQuery(this).attr('checked'));
    });
}
```

On first click, all checkboxes get checked, click it again, and they get unchecked.

Second click, no checkmarks show in the boxes, however, the checked="checked" attribute does appear in the element, and dissapears if clicking the checkall again.

How can I keep them showing the checkmark?

Comment: All you need is `$(which).prop('checked', !this.checked);`, do you really need a function for that ?

Comment: Wait, does `which` reference/select a single element?

Comment: which references a potential list of checkboxes.  This is for a 'check all/un-check all'

Comment: @adeneo yes I do.  So I can use it for more than just one instance...

Comment: That's great, if you feel like you need a function, go head, but a really short one-liner is all you need to do this (see my comment), it would almost be shorter than writing the function name and argument ?

Comment: Normally I would agree... if it was a one or 2 off instance... but it will be used in over 100 tables... so centralizing it is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, `.prop()` would be used instead of `.attr()`. But honestly, it'd be even better to not use either:

```
this.checked = !this.checked;
```

Comment: While this does appear to work.  On checking Firebug, the checkboxes to do have have the `checked` attribute added to them...

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`

```
function CheckToggle(which){
    jQuery(which).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).prop('checked', !jQuery(this).attr('checked'));
    });
}
```